# How change the style of PlaceAutocomplete

Tags: android, google-places-api

First, sorry my English.
I'm implementing a view for search a Address, and I'm using the Places API, my code open a Pending Intent, follow the code:

```
     Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
```

I will like know how to change the style(background color, text color) of this view?

Comment: you cannot modify the PlaceAutocomplete Activity or Fragment, as there no options to do so. If you really want to do it, try implementing your own Activity or Fragment for the same.

Answer (score 1):

It inherits the style of the activity that called it.
I managed to change the colour of the toolbar and search bar ( haven't found a way to change the hint text though)
I also found it only affects Lollipop and up.